# JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION on Brother SDK

Tags: java, android, printing, android-ndk, brother-bpac

Im trying to print a image in Brother SDK in my app.

this is my code:

```
       `myPrinterInfo = myPrinter.getPrinterInfo();
        myPrinterInfo.printerModel = PrinterInfo.Model.QL_810W;
        myPrinterInfo.port = PrinterInfo.Port.NET;
        myPrinterInfo.printMode = PrinterInfo.PrintMode.FIT_TO_PAGE;
        myPrinterInfo.paperSize = PrinterInfo.PaperSize.CUSTOM;
        myPrinterInfo.labelNameIndex = 5;
        myPrinterInfo.isAutoCut = false;
        myPrinterInfo.isCutAtEnd = false;
        myPrinterInfo.orientation = PrinterInfo.Orientation.PORTRAIT;
        myPrinterInfo.valign = PrinterInfo.VAlign.TOP;
        myPrinterInfo.align = PrinterInfo.Align.LEFT;
        myPrinterInfo.halftone = PrinterInfo.Halftone.THRESHOLD;
        myPrinterInfo.ipAddress = "192.168.1.146";
        myPrinterInfo.thresholdingValue = 127;
        myPrinterInfo.pjCarbon = false;
        myPrinterInfo.pjDensity = 5;
        myPrinterInfo.pjFeedMode = PrinterInfo.PjFeedMode.PJ_FEED_MODE_FIXEDPAGE;
        myPrinterInfo.pjPaperKind = PJ_CUT_PAPER;
        myPrinterInfo.rollPrinterCase = PrinterInfo.PjRollCase.PJ_ROLLCASE_OFF;
        myPrinterInfo.paperPosition = PrinterInfo.Align.CENTER;
        myPrinterInfo.numberOfCopies = 1;
```

Im using the 62mmx100mm paper roll and I got this error message:

> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: GetStringUTFChars received NULL jstring
>   08-10 17:33:18.882 31333-31584/br.com.squarebits.brothertest E/art:     in call to GetStringUTFChars
>   08-10 17:33:18.882 31333-31584/br.com.squarebits.brothertest E/art:     from boolean com.brother.ptouch.sdk.JNIWrapper.writeByteInFile(int[], int, java.lang.String, boolean)
>   08-10 17:33:18.882 31333-31584/br.com.squarebits.brothertest E/art: "AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=10 Runnable
>   08-10 17:33:18.882 31333-31584/br.com.squarebits.brothertest E/art:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c99460 self=0xe9594500
>   08-10 17:33:18.882 31333-31584/br.com.squarebits.brothertest E/art:   | sysTid=31584 nice=10 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0xe0b65930
>   08-10 17:33:18.882 31333-31584/br.com.squarebits.brothertest E/art:   | state=R schedstat=( 80462688 29252686 258 ) utm=5 stm=3 core=2 HZ=100
>   08-10 17:33:18.882 31333-31584/br.com.squarebits.brothertest E/art:   | stack=0xe0a63000-0xe0a65000 stackSize=1038KB
>   08-10 17:33:18.882 31333-31584/br.com.squarebits.brothertest E/art:   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
>   08-10 17:33:18.882 31333-31584/br.com.squarebits.brothertest E/art:   native: #00 pc 0035adcf  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+126)
>   08-10 17:33:18.882 31333-31584/br.com.squarebits.brothertest E/art:   native: #01 pc 0033bdeb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+138)
>   08-10 17:33:18.882 31333-31584/br.com.squarebits.brothertest E/art:   native: #02 pc 0024ef71  /system/lib/libart.so (*ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2*+900)
>   08-10 17:33:18.882 31333-31584/br.com.squarebits.brothertest E/art:   native: #03 pc 0024f607  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortVEPKcS2_St9__va_list+54)
>   08-10 17:33:18.882 31333-31584/br.com.squarebits.brothertest E/art:   native: #04 pc 000fbe5d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck6AbortFEPKcz+28)
>   08-10 17:33:18.882 31333-31584/br.com.squarebits.brothertest E/art:   native: #05 pc 001003b9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEbPKcPNS_12JniValueTypeE.constprop.95+2676)
>   08-10 17:33:18.883 31333-31584/br.com.squarebits.brothertest E/art:   native: #06 pc 00108cd5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI17GetStringUTFCharsEP7_JNIEnvP8_jstringPh+376)

If anyone knows how to fix it, please help me :(

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem today, it turns out the android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission was not granted. If you are running on and Android 6 or greater, check your [run time permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for writing to the external storage. Declaring the permission in the manifest is not enough. The brother documentation hints at this at the end of their [manual](http://www.brother.com/product/dev/mobile/android/index.htm).

> 8.3. Android 6 compatibility Since Android 6.0, Users are allowed to change the application’s permissions after installation. Permission to
>   access Android external storage must be granted to use this
>   application.

Comment: Great find, shame to Brother for handling this in such a poor way - no helpful message or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of steps I've done in order to make the printing functional and get rid of this error. I am using the newest Brother SDK 4.6.4.

**1. AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

---

**2. Runtime request for permission**

```
if (context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 8);
}
```

---

**3. build.gradle**

```
targetSdkVersion = 32
```

(lowering to 32 helped me to show the permissions popup on a newer device)

---

**4. [This one did the trick] Adding `workPath` to printer info**

```
PrinterInfo printInfo = printer.getPrinterInfo();
printInfo.workPath = "storage/emulated/0/Download/";
```

Brothers at Brother should work on that developer experience. I hope this helps!