# Brother SDK Calling PrintImage causes JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: GetStringUTFChars received NULL jstring

Tags: java, android, mobile

Currently working with the Brother SDK for a label Printer and when I call Asset Manager, the Bitmap appears but when it is parsed to print image it crashes.

```
if (myPrinter.startCommunication()) {
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
          Bitmap bitmap = null;
          try{
              bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new BufferedInputStream(assetManager.open("meme.bmp")));
             }catch(Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
             }
          PrinterStatus result = myPrinter.printImage(bitmap);
       if (result.errorCode != ErrorCode.ERROR_NONE) {
         Log.d("TAG", "ERROR - " + result.errorCode);
       }
         myPrinter.endCommunication();
}
```

[Stack Readout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWttR.png)

[Debugger printout, with Image Preview.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Esd7.png)

Comment: Is bitmap null perhaps?

Comment: I added the debugger printout, the image is there for preview, but it is null so not sure what is going on.

Comment: Time to look at the implementation of the method mentioned in the JNI error with a debugger.

Comment: I tested the asset manager code section elsewhere in the code base and its also returning the same way as the debugger above. Is there another way of loading a bmp into the Bitmap datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue as well. Have you made sure that the android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permisson is granted.
Having this in the manifest file wasn't enough, but by requesting permisson from the user, this specific error went away.

[Credit to this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49176744/12241614)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone got stuck even if they made sure they have the write permission granted, it was about the working path b-PAC trying to create.

The default path is: `/storage/emulated/0/com.brother.ptouch.sdk/template`

Just define your own path in `PrinterInfo` object. Set the `workPath` variable as such:

```
PrinterInfo mPrintSettings = mPrinter.getPrinterInfo();
mPrintSettings.workPath = "your/custom/work/path";
```

It says in the document that you don't even need the permission if you do so. But I'm going to keep it anyway.

Comment: This is awesome! Fixed our issue with our Brother printer not working with Android 10. Once I passed in a `workPath`, it started working again. Thanks so much!

Comment: Worked for me too, but for those wondering what should the path look like, the one which is functional with me is `mPrintSettings.workPath = "storage/emulated/0/Download/"`;